# How to set build type to 32 bit in Github actions for CMake C++ project

Tags: c++, github, cmake, github-actions

I need to have automated testing on github for a CMake C++ project. For this I want to use a 32 bit Windows machine (some of our packages are only in 32 bit), but I couldn't find an easy method to do this. I have tried to set `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` and `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` in the environment to the x86 compiler, but that did not do anything.

Is there a keyword that I can add either to github actions environment, or to the CMake so that my project does compile to a 32 bit program on github?

Comment: In a typical CMake project you would specify the generator and the architecture, i.e. `cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -A Win32 ...`

Comment: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/setup-msvc-developer-command-prompt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments from [vre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5251059/vre) the `cmake -A Win32` tag works on github! If you also want the host to be x86 run the following command: `cmake -S SOURCEFOLDER -B BUILDFOLDER -T host=x86 -A Win32`

Comment: The option `-A Win32` must not be used with CMake's build tool mode (`--build <dir>`) it is only valid for the configuration step. Newer versions of CMake will error on this.

Comment: You are right thanks!